# Cross platform internationalization

Tags: c#, internationalization, mono, globalization

I'm in the process of writing a cross platform c# application that will run on win/linux using .net/mono.
I want to internationalize the application. Should I use Mono.Unix or System.Globalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Globalization should be supported by Mono if it is part of the standard (which I think it is); Mono.Unix won't be supported by .Net, so I personally would rely on System.Globalization and maybe look at runtime referencing of Mono.Unix at a later date if it proves that you really really really need it...